# Shopify API returns empty cart

Tags: ajax, api, shopify

Using this API: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#add-to-cart

From my messenger bot I call `cart/add.js` multiple times with the `variant id` and `quantity` and it returns a success message, but I call `cart.js` to retrieve the items, the cart is always empty.

I'm adding items to the cart like this:

```
$cartAPI = 'https://'.$shopKey.':'.$shopSecret.'@'.$shopUrl.'/cart/add.js';
$request = $client->request('POST', $cartAPI, [
      'form_params' => [
          'id'        => (int) $productID,
           'quantity' => 1
       ]
]);
```

And retrieving cart like this:

```
$cartAPI = 'https://'.$shopKey.':'.$shopSecret.'@'.$shopUrl.'/cart.js';
$request = $client->get($cartAPI);
```

I tried to include cookies in the Guzzle call like so 
`$this->client = new Client(['cookies' => true]);` and both calls use the same client instance, but it still returns an empty cart.

I don't use CloudFlare or any Caching mechanism for this.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution i figured out here for anyone having the same issue. I needed to use the `cart` cookie. Ended up doing something like:

```
$cartCookie = Cache::tags(['user:' .$userId, 'cookies'])->get('cart');

if (!$cartCookie) {
    $client  = new Client(['cookies' => true]);
} else {
    $cookieJar = CookieJar::fromArray([
        'cart' => $cartCookie,
    ], conf('shop.url'));
    $client = new Client(['cookies' => $cookieJar]);
}
```

Cookie is stored in the cache the first time the user adds an item to the cart and used for recurrent adds. I had to put it in Cache since I'm building a chatbot but you can just use cookies from your browser.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something wrong. Why would you make a call to Shopify with a key and a secret? Are you not selling yourself a little short here? I mean if I examined your source code, and saw a key and secret, I would be able to use that to do anything I want. Is that the goal here? Allowing anyone on the Internet to make you look silly? Shopify has a button you can place anywhere to add products to a cart. You can use that. It is secure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Appreciated. You will not find the secret key if you examined my code. Credentials are put in a unversioned `.env` file and I couldn't put any button since this is for a chatbot. Now, can we focus on the matter here?